# /boot/grub2/i386-pc is on different partition than /. Will grub2 work?

Tags: boot, grub2, partitioning, mount

I have a machine in which `/` is mounted on `/dev/sda1` and `/boot/grub2/i386-pc` is mounted on `/dev/sda2`. I have installed `grub2` properly on this disk, but I am still getting this error:

```
/boot/grub2/i386-pc/normal.mod file not found.
```

Now my question is that Is this setting even possible, i.e having `/`( or `/boot`) on one partition and `/boot/grub2/i386-pc/` on a different partition. If it is possible then please tell me how to solve this problem.

Comment: If I get you correctly, yes you can have boot on different partition, I prefer that.

Comment: I edit my question little bit so that it is more understandable.@George

Comment: Not sure I understand. Most Desktop installs have just / (root). Some server type installs or LVM or LVM with full drive encryption use a separate /boot partition. Post the link to the Create BootInfo summary report. Is part of Boot-Repair:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info

Comment: You can have the grub directory installed to any partition/filesystem by pointing `--boot-directory` to its mountpoint when grub-install, and that filesystem does not necessarily need to be mounted in the real system. For example, sda2 would be used for / and sda1 would be used for /boot, the grub directory can resides in an sda3 (which will not have an fstab entry), you can mount it to /mnt just before grub-install, and run `grub-install --boot-directory /mnt /dev/sda`. Though with this type of configuration you'll need to write your own grub.cfg. update-grub most likely wouldn't work.

Comment: Personally I do that with my UEFI installation. I mount my EFI system partition (which is NOT used for /boot) to /mnt just before grub-install and then run `grub-install --efi-directory /mnt --boot-directory /mnt --removable`, and I don't have an fstab entry for the partition and only mount it (to /mnt or even mount it with udisksctl) when I need to update/change stuff in it.